# Flutter - Pass Navigating Widget Name Dynamically

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation, flutter-widget

I have created a Button Widget to avoid duplication of code as there are multiple buttons on the screen. Clicking on each button should take it to a different screen.

```
class ButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final buttonText;
  final destination;
  ButtonWidget({this.buttonText, this.destination});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
            switch (destination) {
              case 'signUp':
               return SignUp();
               break;
              case 'signIn':
               return SignIn();
               break;
              case 'SignInGoogle':
               return SignInGoogle();
               break;
              default:
               return SignUp();
            }
          }));
        },
        child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  minHeight: 6.5 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                  maxHeight: 7.9 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(4 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier),
                ),
                color: AppTheme.topBarBackgroundColor,
              ),
              child: Center(child: Text(buttonText)),
            )));
  }
}
```

On Tap I want to navigate to the destination widget. But that doesn't seem to work. I am calling the ButtonWidget in following manner:

```
ButtonWidget(
   buttonText: Strings.signUp,
   destination: 'signUp',
)
```

Comment: Why don't you pass the widget directly instead of its name. Like final Widget destination;

Comment: Does your `ButtonWidget` always navigate to other screens? Is there a possibility that it will pop the navigation stack or have a different tap behavior?

Comment: always navigate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pass the widget instead of a name representation of it:**

```
class ButtonWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final buttonText;
  final Widget destination;
  ButtonWidget({this.buttonText, this.destination});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => destination
          ));
        },
        child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  minHeight: 6.5 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                  maxHeight: 7.9 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(4 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier),
                ),
                color: AppTheme.topBarBackgroundColor,
              ),
              child: Center(child: Text(buttonText)),
            )));
  }
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
ButtonWidget(
   buttonText: Strings.signUp,
   destination: SignUp(),
)
```

Comment: Thank you. For some odd reason it wasn't working earlier.